# Accidentally activated security in GraphDB Free

Tags: authentication, graphdb

I accidentally activated security in my local installation of GraphDB Free on my machine, resulting in a login screen which I cannot go past (see below). Could someone please advise on how to deactivate the login feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by taking a look at the [official documentation](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/pdf/GraphDB.pdf) (missed it the first time I looked there).

Default credentials are `admin` and `root`.

[image]